# LibreOffice cpu usage 50% in Ubuntu and Xubuntu 15.10

Tags: libreoffice, cpu

When I load 400 pages of ODT document in Ubuntu 15.10 and Xubuntu 15.10, cpu usage becomes 31%. It is soffice.bin file.
After editing, cpu usage becomes 50% (cpu0: 100%, cpu1: below 10% or vice versa)
After saving that, it comes back to 31%. But it is still high.

BTW, Linux Mint XFCE latest version has no problem. Just below 10% usage.
What's the problem?
Isn't that almost same distro?

Comment: How much memory does your computer have, and what versions of Libreoffice are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved.
Latest LO has problem while 4.4 version has no problem.
I found mint xfce has LO 4.4.
So I deleted LO 5.0 and installed old version in xubuntu.
Problem solved.
But developers should fix something for new version.